# GET method gives success but PUT method gives 401 despite same credentials

Tags: javascript, axios, backend, http-status-code-401

### The problem Overview

- When getting products using a `GET` method everything works
- when trying to update a product using `PUT` method I get 401 unauthorized
- I use same credentials for both methods
- The bearer token is global scope, I should be authorized to do anything to a given product

### The code

> GET

```
// javascript
const axiosOptions = {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
  }
}

const onAllClick = async () => {
  const result = await axios.get(`https://api.printify.com/v1/shops/${shopId}/products.json?limit=30`, axiosOptions );
  const products = result.data.data; 
  console.log(products);
}
```

> PUT

```
javascript
const axiosTagUpdateOptions = {
  headers: {
    "Authorization": `Bearer ${token}`
  },
  data: {
    title:"New product title"
  }
}


const onEditTagsClick = async (productID, tags) => {
  await axios.put(`https://api.printify.com/v1/shops/${shopId}/products/60e0a5c198be4c1296798c27.json`, axiosTagUpdateOptions)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```

### Problem

The get function works perfectly fine. But whenever I try to modify a product using the put method, like the [documentation](https://developers.printify.com/#update-a-product) says, I get a 401 unauthorized error. But I'm using the same token for both the get and the put method. The token is set to global scope (for testing purposes) so I should be able to edit and delete products at will.

I read through the API documentation and it looks like I got everything right. I have the bearer token as the header and in the body I included the value I want to modify. Obviously the request is going through, I just don't know why it keeps saying I'm unauthorized to edit the product. I would have liked to edit the product from the printify UI, but the UI won't let me add tags (which is really annoying)... So I'm forced to update via a put method.

I couldn't find any reason for why I am getting this error, can anyone help me?

Comment: thats up to your backend. you'll have to research that side

Comment: Print the headers before the call and check if the token has any value or is `undefined`

Comment: The 2nd arg to `axios.put()` is the data. The config object is the 3rd arg. See https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosputurl-data-config. **Closing as a typo**

Comment: @Phil yea, that was the problem. I'm still new to axios, so I didn't know, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For put request you must pass data as a parameter and not in axiosOptions.

```js
const onEditTagsClick = async (productID, tags) => {
  await axios.put(`https://api.printify.com/v1/shops/${shopId}/products/60e0a5c198be4c1296798c27.json`, data, axiosTagUpdateOptions)
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
}
```